# What happens with the TTL when the message is delivered in persistent mode and RabbitMQ server is restarted?

Tags: rabbitmq

I couldn`t find anything in RabbitMQ docs, I know how TTL works discarding messages that haven't been consumed after X amount of time, but how does it work when the message is written to disk (persistent mode) and the server unexpectedly restart, does the current value for the TTL start all over again, or its current value is somehow preserved and when the server is up again, it continues counting down since it last value?

I have done localhost tests and it seems that the TTL gets preserved, but I don't quite sure.